# Orbot: Refusing to connect to IPv4 address because Port has no IPv4Traffic set

Tags: orbot, connection

When trying to connect to Tor using Orbot, the process stops at 10% with the error message `Refusing to connect to IPv4 address because Port has no IPv4Traffic set` appears. Trying different bridges doesn't change the result.

Comment: Have you made changes to your tor configuration? The tor configuration format (the torrc) has a `NoIPv4Traffic` SOCKS port flag, and it sounds like yours is enabled. This flag prevents you from connecting to IPv4 addresses.

Comment: please provide your `torrc` config - it's impossible to see the reason just with these data